# jmeter learning topics for jmeter testing

Tags: automated-testing, load-testing, api-testing, stress-testing, performance-testing

What are the topic comes under learning j-meter testing?
like for database testing,login/logout testing,full project flow testing ,load testing of mobile api's

Comment: You can also learn about Pre and Post processor.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some major topics when it comes to JMeter:

**Major topics**

1. Sampler
2. Timers
3. Assertions
4. Controllers
5. Processors
6. HTTP proxy setting
7. listerners

Also, Please check the below websites to learn more about JMeter:

1. [Guru 99](https://www.guru99.com/jmeter-tutorials.html)
2. [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/index.htm)
3. [Toolsqa](http://toolsqa.com/jmeter-tutorial/)
4. [blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/getting-started-jmeter-basic-tutorial)
5. [softwaretestinghelp](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/jmeter-tutorials/)

Answer (score 0):

The topics are covered in [JMeter User Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html) in particular:

- [Building a Database Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html)
- [Logging in to a web-site](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#logging_in)
- [Building a Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-test-plan.html)

Also you can consider attending free [JMeter Academy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blazemeter-news/blazemeter-launches-jmeter-academy) which is probably the fastest and the most efficient way of ramping up in JMeter tool.

The general advice is that your load test needs to represent real life usage of your application as close as possible, given each JMeter's virtual user represents a real user you should be good to go, otherwise your load test won't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Thank you sir for your advice ,this is very helpful for me.